# How to display reports between two different dates on a monthly basis?

Tags: excel

The problem that I'm facing currently is I have a start date and end date for multiple different items. What I want to do is be able to see when a `report` would be due at each given month that it's accounted for with a `end report` (+14 days from end date). For example:

[image: Start-End]
The Lookup tab that I have for reference of the dates above to be able to match the months looks like this:
[image: FY19 Dates]

Now I'm having trouble creating a formula that would actually work with this. If I'm thinking correctly it would be something like,

`IF Start Date != Start Month then IF Start Date is between March Dates, "Report", . . . IF End Date hits, add 14 days, then "End Report" on given month after 14 days.`

So for the example above the outcome would look like the following:
[image: End Result]

This is the end result that I would want in the end. Due note that August for Battlefield 5 is supposed to be blank due to the game ending on 8/19/2018, +14 days for a end report: 9/2/2018 is the `End Report` date so their would not be a `Report` in August for that given scenario. (I think this is possible but not 100% sure for the August scenario)

I am open to any kind of formulas/Arrays/VBA's that would accomplish this task. I'm just having difficulty coming up with a solution for this that has been bugging me for a while, so any help is much appreciated!!

If anything needs to be further explained please let me know and I will do my best as an edit to this post.

-Maykid

Comment: In your example of expected output. For your last line, should you have the end of the report in January (December 25 + 14 days => January?)

Comment: @RenauV Yes you are correct I must have missed that when I was making the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you explained, you could just have a simple formula as such (no need for VBA):

**LOCALISATION OF THIS FORMULA (E2) UNDER FEBRUARY 2018 in the picture attached**

```
=IF(AND(MONTH($C2)=MONTH(E$1),MONTH($C2+14)=MONTH(F$1)),"",IF(AND(MONTH($C2+14)=MONTH(E$1),YEAR($C2+14)=YEAR(E$1)),"End Report",IF(AND($B2<E$1,($C2+14)>E$1),"Report","")))
```

And then you can drag this formula.

I hope it helps.
BR

[image]

Comment: This works!! Thank you so much! Just for clarification on the Date parameters that you have, are you essentially having the same day for each month? Or is it corresponding to the Fiscal Start date of each month? Or really, how are you formatting the date parameters to account for month/year in the formula?

Comment: For the date on the top row? It is the first of the month. This should work like a charm! Happy I could help.